# How to refer to css file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I use XAMPP and CI 2.14
(I know it's sounds ridiculous, but...) I don't know how to refer to a css file from a view. I've read and tried a lot of examples but, obviously I do something wrong...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

The base url is: `http://localhost/myapp/`

Where should I put then main.css file (now is in the webroot/myapp/css folder), and how to reference it from a codeigniter view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create folder assets:

path is: /assets/css/your_file.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/your_file.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: that is workin! (this one is the only one, wich I've not tried :-(

Comment: can you prefer a way to put css outside the webroot? I would like to put the myapp folder (with system and application folders) out of my webroot folder...

Comment: in your view file (layout) write <style><?= file_get_contents('../your_file.css') ?></style>, but this is bed practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the css folder inside the application folder, like this:

/yourapp/application/css/

And then

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>application/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```